# How to enable yum repo inside a docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile, sh, yum, rhel7

I need to setup nodejs,yarn inside my docker container inside RHEL7. When am using yum to install those tools, its is saying yum command not found, i realised yum itself not present in the container. please help how to create/enable yum in a dockerfile

DockerFile:

```
FROM selenium/node-chrome:x.xx.1.proxy
RUN yum install nodejs
```

Expected Result: Nodejs should be installed
Actual Result:

```
Step 2/8 : RUN yum install nodejs
 ---> Running in 0d8e2ca0fb33
/bin/sh: 1: yum: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c yum install nodejs' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

Please help in resolving the issue by setting up yum in docker container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yum is a Red Hat tool, but [selenium/node-chrome](https://hub.docker.com/r/selenium/node-chrome/dockerfile) is based off [ubuntu](https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu). Use `apt-get` instead.

- [selenium/node-chrome](https://hub.docker.com/r/selenium/node-chrome/dockerfile): `FROM selenium/node-base:3.5.3-boron`
- [selenium/node-base](https://hub.docker.com/r/selenium/node-base/dockerfile): `FROM selenium/base:3.5.3-boron`
- [selenium/base](https://hub.docker.com/r/selenium/base/dockerfile): `FROM ubuntu:16.04`